# Deploy solution through sharepoint designer - 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

i have created an asp.net page for our client. He is asking me to deploy this page through sharepoint designer to view from his own SharePoint server.

Is is possible to deploy a solution through designer software.

This is the requirement for the project

1. Create a registration page and save data in sharepoint list
2. It will have some jquery files and images

We are using sharepoint server 2007 version. Is it possible to push these files and .dll into GAC everything through SharepointDesigner2007.

Please suggest some answers.

Comment: How did you create a DLL using SPD?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deploy DLLs using SharePint designer and you have to use WSP. Checkout [SharePoint Solution Installer](http://sharepointinstaller.codeplex.com/) which can help you make the insallation smoother.